# I want to insert the data to the database

Tags: c#

I want insert the data into the database.

```
string pa = "4898";  
string equery="Insert into Users(pas)values('"+pa+"')";
```

while I inserting the data to the database,its says string or binary data would be truncated the statement has been terminated. So I changed `nvarchar(50)` into `nvarchar(max)` in the table.

And these statement has been executed and saved in the database of unreadable format like `傉䝎਍ਚ` this. And how can be over come this problem and save the data in the database as "4898".

```
private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string password = "4898";
    string equery="Insert into Users(name,gender,dateofbirth,age,fathername,
                                      address,citiy,state,country,zipcode,
                                      mobile,phone,email,jobtitle,
                                      dateofjoin,pic,passwords)
                             values('"+nametxt.Text.ToString().Trim()+"',
                                     @gender,
                                     '"+dateofbirth.Text.ToString().Trim()+"',
                                     '"+age.Value.ToString().Trim()+"',
                                     '"+fathertxt.Text.ToString().Trim()+"',
                                    '"+addresstxt.Text.ToString().Trim()+"',
                                  '"+citiytxt.Text.ToString().Trim()+"',
                                  '"+statetxt.Text.ToString().Trim()+"',
                                  '"+country.Text.ToString().Trim()+"',
                                  '"+ziptxt.Text.ToString().Trim()+"',
                                  '"+mobiletxt.Text.ToString().Trim()+"',
                                  '"+phonetxt.Text.ToString().Trim()+"',
                                  '"+emailtxt.Text.ToString().Trim()+"',
                                  '"+jobtxt.Text.ToString().Trim()+
                                  "','"+dateofjoin.Text.ToString().Trim()+"',
                                  '"+password+"',@pic)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(equery, con);

    if(male.Checked)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender","Male");
    else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender","Female");

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(stream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pic", pic);

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully");
    idtxt.Text = "";
    nametxt.Text = "";
    age.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(null);
    male.Checked = false;
    female.Checked = false;
    dateofbirth.Text = "";
    fathertxt.Text = "";
    addresstxt.Text = "";
    citiytxt.Text = "";
    statetxt.Text = "";
    country.Text = "";
    ziptxt.Text = "";
    mobiletxt.Text = "";
    phonetxt.Text = "";
    emailtxt.Text = "";
    dateofjoin.Text = "";
    jobtxt.Text = "";
    pictureBox1.Image = null;
}
```

Comment: `傉䝎਍ਚ` is the start of a PNG image interpreted as UTF-16.

Comment: Please put brake point at equery and copy that query and try to run at sql server. Check what data is inserting....

Comment: show the table structure and the value of equery during debugging

Comment: Can we see more of your code ??Because even nvarchar(50) is enough for `"4898"` .

Comment: Your saveClick event shows you are trying to save a lot more than just pas of "4898" in that one statement. Your SQL Command is also subject to SQL Injection, and I think you'd be better off trying to use more examples of parameterised queries as you've done with cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender","Male");. What would happen to your current query if say nametxt.Text was "Tom O'Rielly"???

Comment: As a sidepoint, why are you not using parameters for all of the fields? You should be, google `SQL Injection`.

Comment: Check `Dominic Kexel`  answer you have intercahnged password value with pic ,Thats why you were getting errors for data length and now when you extended its value to `MAX` you are getting `傉䝎਍ਚ` instead of your password value .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your insert statement:

```
"Insert into Users(... pic,passwords) values (... '"+password+"',@pic)";
```

it seems that you interchanged `pic` and `passwords`.

---

Also, as others already pointed out in the comments, you should use only parameterised queries (to prevent SQL Injection), especially when handling text inserted by an user or any other untrusted source.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Logical error in your code. Interchange

```
'"+password+"',@pic)";
```

in your string equery.
By the way a suggestion! It is better to use 'linq to Sql' rather than query pass method! Because 'Linq to Sql' does every thing for you. you just have to give values :)

Comment: LINQ to SQL isn't suited for all circumstances, for example it is incompatible with SQL CE databases. In some situations it can also add unnecessary overhead to a program when a simple query would suffice.